# Get value from hidden field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `<input type="hidden" value="" id='h_v' class='h_v'>`  Using jQuery I want to alert the user to this value .

I am using

```
var hv = $('#h_v).text();
alert('x');
```

But its not working, any clues!

Comment: The revisions done to this question are awful.  It completely removes the reason from vision why the asker was originally having issues.  And makes some of the questions point out things that aren't there anymore.

Comment: I've rolled the question back to its original presentation; the revisions/edits done by other users effectively corrected the entire list of problems the question was asking about, meaning the question no longer made sense ("But it's no longer working" is false) and the accepted answer didn't make sense (it referred to parts of the question that didn't exist). To anyone who edited the question to "improve" the code; please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code TLDR? Only edit question code to format it, never to "fix" it. Post an answer instead

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `text()`

```
var hv = $('#h_v').val();
alert(hv);
```

You had these problems:

- Single quotes was not closed
- You were using `text()` for an input field
- You were echoing `x` rather than variable `hv`

Comment: I am trying to trigger this alert with an append, and the hidden field is in the append div.

Comment: @Jean: I don't undertand that, please be more specific.

Comment: Please check for the updated question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091670/get-value-from-hidden-field-after-append-jquery

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to assign identifier to the hidden field; you can use name or class with selector like:

```
$('input[name=hiddenfieldname]').val();
```

or with assigned class:

```
$('input.hiddenfieldclass').val();
```

Comment: `<div class="selected-imsi"><input type="hidden" id="imsi_sel" name="selected_imsi[]" value="'+datum.id+'" />` how can I check the value is empty or not ?

Comment: @MrFaisal simply do this check: if ($('#imsi_sel').val().length == 0) {
      console.log('imsi_sel value is empty');
}

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
var hv = $('#h_v').val();
alert(hv);
```

Answer (score 6):

html

```html
<input type="hidden" value="hidden value" id='h_v' class='h_v'>
```

js

```js
var hv = $('#h_v').attr("value");
alert(hv);
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/F8MmQ)

Comment: How can I check the value is empty or not ?

Answer (score 5):

```
var hiddenFieldID = "input[id$=" + hiddenField + "]";
var requiredVal= $(hiddenFieldID).val();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = $('#h_v').val();
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing the quotes in 
`var hv = $('#h_v).text();`
would help I guess

Comment: `.text()` is not working on input-fields. rather use `.val()`