# Get value from hidden field after append - jQuery

Tags: jquery

When #sw is clicked, I need `alert(dc)`; to be triggered

```
<form name="sc" action="" method="">
<div class="si" id="seli" style="position:absolute; left:15px; top:200px; width:260px;">
<select>
<?  do { $k = $row_w['k']; ?>
<option value="<? echo $k1; ?>"><? echo $1k; ?></option>
<? } while ($row_kw = mysql_fetch_assoc($kw)); ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="save" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="dc" class="dct" value="5"/>
<div id="sw" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
</form>
```

and the jquery code

```
$('#sw').bind('click',function(e) {

                                                 var x = (e.target.id);

                                                 var y = x.substr(5,1);
                                                 var dn = ($(e.target).text());
                                                 var x1 = '<div class="s" id=s'+y+' style="margin-bottom:3px; text-align:left; border-bottom:#cccccc solid thin;">'+do_nm+'</div>';

                                                 $('.si').append(x1);
                                                 $('#'+x).fadeOut('slow');

                                                 var dc1= ('#dc').val();
                                                 alert(dc);

                                                 });
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You need to provide more information. What's wrong with the code you have? Any error messages? It makes life a lot easier for potential answerers if you describe the problem, it saves us time of having to decrypt your code looking for what might be a problem.

Comment: There are no error messages, all I need to get an alert from the value of the hidden field, when the function is triggered

Comment: you should consider an acception or give some more information what/why the provided solutions won't work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. I not completely sure of the question, but if you replace:

```
var dc1= ('#dc').val();
alert(dc);
```

with:

```
var dc = $('#dc')[0].value;
alert(dc);
```

You must use [0] because jQuery's $() returns a collection of items, and the collections does not have a value property, but the instance in the collection does.

Comment: `.val()` is basically the same as `[0].value` (first will take jQuery overload, which internally requests the `value`-property)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var dc1= ('#dc').val();
  var dc1= ('#dc').val();
 alert(dc);
```

with

```
 alert($('#dc').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got a typo in there

```
var dc1= ('#dc').val();
alert(dc);
```

make it

```
var dc = $('#dc').val();
alert(dc);
```

also: be sure that the id is unique in your dom! otherwise you might want to work with your class:

```
var dc = $('.dct').val();
alert(dc);
```