# jQuery access input hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access `<input type="hidden">` tag's `value` attribute using jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from hidden field - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091374/get-value-from-hidden-field-jquery)

Answer (score 393, accepted):

You can access hidden fields' values with `val()`, just like you can do on any other input element:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="zyx" value="bar" />

alert($('input#foo').val());
alert($('input[name=zyx]').val());
alert($('input[type=hidden]').val());
alert($(':hidden#foo').val());
alert($('input:hidden[name=zyx]').val());
```

Those all mean the same thing in this example.

Comment: alert($('input[type=hidden]#foo').val()); This finds the hidden variable with id foo . This search is more specific.

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq alert($('#foo').val()); Is just as specific. Because an id is unique in the DOM. Therefor it will always find just one element if the html follows the standards. Unless you use the statement to check if the element is hidden or not.

Comment: what is faster ? $('#foo') or $('input:hidden#foo') ? i suspect the second since more search info given but not sure how it's implemented, so don't know if my feeling is correct. EDIT: ok i have my answer thanks to Abel comment,id only, ie  #foo is faster.

Comment: Why not only: `$('#foo').val();`. Simple, straightforward. And works in all cases with a specific `ID`, irrespective of whether the field is `hidden'.

Answer (score 19):

The most efficient way is by ID.

```
$("#foo").val(); //by id
```

You can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering?hl=it#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Answer (score 18):

There's a jQuery selector for that:

```
// Get all form fields that are hidden
var hidden_fields = $( this ).find( 'input:hidden' );

// Filter those which have a specific type
hidden_fields.attr( 'text' );
```

Will give you all hidden input fields and filter by those with a specific `type=""`.

Comment: Note that this will also match elements that have a CSS display value of none, elements that have a width and height set to 0, and elements that have a hidden ancestor (https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 6):

**To get value, use:**

```
$.each($('input'),function(i,val){
    if($(this).attr("type")=="hidden"){
        var valueOfHidFiled=$(this).val();
        alert(valueOfHidFiled);
    }
});
```

**or:**

```
var valueOfHidFiled=$('input[type=hidden]').val();
alert(valueOfHidFiled);
```

**To set value, use:**

```
$('input[type=hidden]').attr('value',newValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about `<input type="hidden">`:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').val()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select an individual hidden field, you can select it through the different selectors of jQuery :

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" name="hiddenField" class="hiddenField"/> 


$("#hiddenField").val(); //by id
$("[name='hiddenField']").val(); // by name
$(".hiddenField").val(); // by class
```

Comment: Input hidden does not have a style class property

Answer (score 3):

If you have an asp.net HiddenField you need to:

To access HiddenField Value:

```
$('#<%=HF.ClientID%>').val()  // HF = your hiddenfield ID
```

To set HiddenFieldValue

```
$('#<%=HF.ClientID%>').val('some value')   // HF = your hiddenfield ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch out if you want to retrieve a boolean value from a hidden field!

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="SomeBoolean" value="False"/>
```

(An input like this will be rendered by ASP MVC if you use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeBoolean)`.)

Then the following will return a string `'False'`, not a JS boolean!

```
var notABool = $('#SomeBoolean').val();
```

If you want to use the boolean for some logic, use the following instead:

```
var aBool = $('#SomeBoolean').val() === 'True';
if (aBool) { /* ...*/ }
```

Answer (score -2):

Most universal way is to take value by name. It doesn't matter if its input or select form element type.

```
var value = $('[name="foo"]');
```