# How to set the value of a input hidden field through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

I am trying to call the `resetyear` function and it's getting called also, but the flow stops at `alert("over")`. It doesn't transfer its control to `resetmaster`.

```
    String flag = "";
    flag = (String) session.getAttribute("flag");
    System.out.println("flag = " + flag);
    if (flag == null) {
        flag = "";
    }
    if (flag.equals("yes")) {
%>   
<script>
   
   alert(1);
  // resetyear();
    dontreset();
    //document.getElementById("checkyear").value = "1";
    //alert(document.getElementById("checkyear").value);
    
</script>
<%} else if(flag.equals("no"))
    {%>
<script>
    alert(2);
    //document.getElementById("checkyear").value = "2";
    //alert(document.getElementById("checkyear").value);
    resetyear();
</script>
<%}else{}%>


function resetyear(){

if(confirm("DO YOU WANT TO RESET THE YEAR?"))
{
    alert("hello");
    //document.forms['indexform'].action = "resetmaster";
    //alert(document.forms['indexform'].action);
    //document.forms['indexform'].submit();  
    alert("over");
    form.action = "resetmaster";
    form.submit();
    alert(1);
}
```

Comment: try putting your html *before* the script thats trying to act on it. What is the "<%} else if (flag != "") {%>" for?

Comment: @underscorePez thank you buddy. I changed the whole code. Instead of using hidden tag, I have directly called the function from the if condition. I have again modified the question. Please check and suggest me answer

Comment: Have the edits made the question completely divorced from the title and answers?

Answer (score 96):

For me it works:

```
document.getElementById("checkyear").value = "1";
alert(document.getElementById("checkyear").value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zKNqg/

Maybe your JS is not executed and you need to add a function() {} around it all.

Comment: But then I will have to call that function which i don't want . i want it to set based on if condition.

Comment: if you make just function() {} (without a name for the function) then the function is called onload.

Comment: at least when i use jquery it works like this: $(function() {});

Comment: thank you buddy. I changed the whole code. Instead of using hidden tag, I have directly called the function from the if condition. I have again modified the question. Please check and suggest me answer

Answer (score 9):

You need to run your script after the element exists.  Move the `<input type="hidden" name="checkyear" id="checkyear" value="">` to the beginning.

Comment: thank you buddy. I changed the whole code. Instead of using hidden tag, I have directly called the function from the if condition. I have again modified the question. Please check and suggest me answer

Answer (score 7):

It seems to work fine in Google Chrome. Which browser are you using?
Here the proof http://jsfiddle.net/CN8XL/

Anyhow you can also access to the input value parameter through the `document.FormName.checkyear.value`. You have to wrap in the input in a `<form>` tag like with the proper `name` attribute, like shown below:

```
<form name="FormName">
    <input type="hidden" name="checkyear" id="checkyear" value="">
</form>
```

Have you considered using the **jQuery** Library? Here are the [docs for `.val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: thank you buddy. I changed the whole code. Instead of using hidden tag, I have directly called the function from the if condition. I have again modified the question. Please check and suggest me answer

Comment: .val() is unable to act on hidden elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979772/set-value-of-hidden-field-in-a-form-using-jquerys-val-doesnt-work

Comment: are you sure, zamber? I don't think so https://jsfiddle.net/rcegvttm/ (I used jquery 1.12, try also with 2.x or 3.x works anyway) another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I will try - determine if your code with alerts is actually rendered. I see some server "if" code in what you posted, so may be condition to render javascript is not satisfied. So, on the page you working on, right-click -> view source. Try to find the js code there. Please tell us if you found the code on the page.

Comment: thank you buddy. I changed the whole code. Instead of using hidden tag, I have directly called the function from the if condition. I have again modified the question. Please check and suggest me answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code for setting value for hidden input is correct. Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncbD2/). Maybe you have some conditions in your `if` statements that are not allowing your scripts to execute.

Comment: thank you buddy. I changed the whole code. Instead of using hidden tag, I have directly called the function from the if condition. I have again modified the question. Please check and suggest me answer