# Cypress jS set value of hidden input

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am experimenting with cypressjs and I am trying to set a value on an hidden input. (I am using material ui, and with a select/search box).

I would like to know if it's possible somehow to set the value of a hidden input (this is what I have on the browser):

```
<input name="search" type="hidden" id="search-simple" 
 value="1234"
```

How can I replicate it in my tests?
I have tried to use `type` with `force:true` but no luck.

```
cy.get('#search-simple').type('ddc66ac588c4ae5d70683cb16729a7e8', { force: true });
```

I also tried to simulate the whole interaction with the UI, but still didn't get it to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

By nature, Cypress gives you native Javascript access to the DOM.

In your case, you could do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19232938/8166701):

```
cy.get('#search-simple').then(elem => {
    elem.val('some text');
});
```

Comment: I found the element value needed to be set with `elem.val('some text');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [invoke](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke) function of Cypress:

```
cy.get('#search-simple').invoke('val', 'ddc66ac588c4ae5d70683cb16729a7e8')
```