# how to access input tag in form with jquery?(include hidden type)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, hidden

I looking for how to access input tag in form via jquery.

I made something like below :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>test </title>
<script src="/resources/gtl_portal/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/gtl_portal/js/comon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="a" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br/>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="numbervalidation"><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenParam" value="hidden parameters"><br/>

    <a href="#" onclick="chk()">press</a><br/>
</form>
<script>
    function chk(){
        checkValidation('a');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in common.js

```
function checkValidation(formName){
    var form = $('#' + formName);

    form.children('input').each(function(k){
        var obj = $(this); 
        console.log(obj.val());
    }
};
```

I can get value from input tags without hidden type. How can I get hidden type also at once. I found follow article. But if I use this, it looks have to iterate form twice which I do not want to.

Link : [jQuery access input hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value)

Is there any way to access hidden and not hidden at once?

Thanks :D

P.S/ I also curious about access multiple selector. I have tried

```
form.children('input, textarea, select').each(function(i){//do something});
```

but does not work. Would you find anything wrong from here?

Comment: You code is just working fine http://jsfiddle.net/SjDe2/48/

Comment: You can always give the input fields id's.  But since it seems you want to get the values of all the input fields.  I suggest checking out TJ's answer.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes, indeed. I do not know why it ignores hidden values in yesterday. probably my mistake:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector) selector. It selects all `<input>` elements including hidden inputs

```
$(":input");
```

Simply selecting the elements by tag name like `$("input");` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Getting hidden input just works, see following code below:

```js
console.log($('input'))
function show(){
   $('input').attr('type','text')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden">
<button onclick="show()" >show hidden fields</button>
```