# Selector for hidden fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to get fields that are hidden because of the CSS overflow?

`$('input:not('visible')')` does not do the trick!

Comment: Could you post the code snippet which you are working on? It helps to give your question some context.

Comment: I cant post the snippet because its too huge. 
Let's just say that I have a table with style overflow:auto 
and i want to exclude the fields not visible because of the overflow

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with it. `overflow: auto` should produce a scrollbar in which the content should still be accessible/visible.

Comment: try this `$('input[type=hidden]')` from here


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value

Comment: Then show us a minimal demo that reproduces your problem. See the "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" guidelines.

Comment: yes thats the problem overflow:auto produces a scrollbar that makes the field still visible. I want to exclude fields that are not visible unless you use the scrollbar

Comment: @medz, you can just post the little snippet that you are currently working on, rather than the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

```
var visible = $('input').filter(function() {
   return ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none');
});
```