# Returning (hidden?) values from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to programming in general and jquery in particular.  I am building an ASP MVC project that uses the following plugin for a star rating system:

https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating

However, I am having a difficult time accessing the value for the database once the user selects a rating.  My current code is as follows:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <span class="star">
                        <input id="input-id" type="radio" value="alert($('input#input-id').val())" class="rating" data-size="lg">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
} 
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/star-rating.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/theme-krajee-svg.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/theme-krajee-svg.js"></script>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    }
```

When I inspect the HTML after loading the page, I can see that the plugin changes:

```
<input id="input-id" type="radio" value="alert($('input#input-id').val())" class="rating" data-size="lg">
```

To:

```
<input id="input-id" type="radio" value=//whatever user rates class="rating hide" data-size="lg">
```

So it seems maybe I am returning some type of hidden input?  I read this link, but nothing worked:

[jQuery access input hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value)

I must be doing something wrong.  Any help would be much appreciate by this novice!

Comment: `value=//whatever user rates` - literally that?

Comment: No.  Sorry for being unclear.  The value will be whatever star the user clicks on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a `hidden` field but it is `radio` field only and the plugin which you are using for star rating adds a `hide` class to it so it is not visible, but if you want to get the value of it then you can use,

```
$('input#input-id').val();
```

but not in its `value` attribute instead you need to use it in your form submission or in your code when you are posting data to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it on `onChange` function and get the value of `input` like below:

```
 $("#input-id").change(function () {
     var atrvalue = $(this).attr('value'); // get the value
     alert(atrvalue);
 });
```

check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/tao7y4np/) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually very simple. All I had to do is add a name="Rating" attribute and change "type" from radio to number(text works too). Here is the revised line that works for me:

```
<input id="input-id" type="number" value="1" class="rating" data-size="lg" name="Rating">
```