# reading hidden custom attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-attribute

I have custom attribute tag in my html without id as the number can vary for them

```
<input type="hidden" cus_control="offer_1" value="123456">
<input type="hidden" cus_control="offer_2" value="1UYREST">
```

Now I want to read the value of offer_1 and offer_2 which is 123456 and 1UYREST respectively using jquery or javascript.
How will I achieve this as I don't have id for them?

Comment: Note that `cus_control` is not a valid attribute for a `input` element, so your HTML is invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery access input hidden value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can target the attribute it self

```
var value = $('input["cus-control=offer_1"]').val();
```

Note that you should be using data-attributes, and not invalid custom attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try the hidden selector
https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

```
var hiddenElements = $( "body" ).find( ":hidden" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way.

```
var hiddenElements = $( "body" ).find( "input:hidden" ).not( "script" );
hiddenElements.each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('sfc_control'))
      {
          var control_value = $(this).val();
          var control_name = $(this).attr('cus_control');
      }

    });
```

Thanks for the suggestions