# How do I get the values of classes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
console.log($('.package_ids').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids[]" name="package_ids[]" value="6" />
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids[]" name="package_ids[]" value="775" />
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids[]" name="package_ids[]" value="7207" />
```

I'm getting the right results when submitting this as a form. But when I get the value using jQuery I'm getting `undefined`.

I'm hoping to get something like an array `[6, 775, 7207]`.

Comment: `package_ids[]` is an invalid class name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery access input hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value)

Comment: No. This is a different question Rafael.

Answer (score 2):

`package_ids[]` cannot be a class name. To get the expected array, you can use `.map` as follows:

```js
const arr = $('.package_ids').map((i,elem) => +$(elem).val()).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" class="package_ids" name="package_ids[]" value="6"/>
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids" name="package_ids[]" value="775"/>
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids" name="package_ids[]" value="7207"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select the items with their `name` property, *e.g.*:

```js
let values = [];
$('[name="package_ids[]"]').each(function (i, v) {
  values.push($(v).val());
});
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids[]" name="package_ids[]" value="6" />
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids[]" name="package_ids[]" value="775" />
<input type="hidden" class="package_ids[]" name="package_ids[]" value="7207" />
```