# Reading asp HiddenField in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In .NET 4.5...

I am trying to read this hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="test2" runat="server" Value="" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="static"/>
```

which the value is being set in the code behind here:

```
public static string TestSessionValue
        {
            get
            {
                object value = HttpContext.Current.Session["TestSessionValue"];
                return value == null ? "" : (string)value;
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["TestSessionValue"] = value;
            }
        }

TestSessionValue = String.Format("EmployeeCredential_ViewList.aspx?" + Employeeid + "={0}&" + StrIsadmin + "={1}", _empCredential.EmployeeId, IsAdmin);

test2.Value = TestSessionValue;
```

and then I am trying to read the value in javascript like so:

```
var hv = $('input[id$=test2]').val();
```

I have also tried this without success:

```
var hv = $('#test2').val();
```

How do I successfully read an asp HiddenField value in javascript?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? That affects how the `ClientIDMode` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to remove `Visible="false"` then it will work or use this `Visible="true"`

So please Replace this:-

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="test2" runat="server" Value="" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="static"/>
```

with:-

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="test2" runat="server" Value="" Visible="true" ClientIDMode="static"/>
```

then try to get value either by

`$("#test2").val()`

or whatever you have written to get the value

Hope it will help?

Comment: Completely overlooked that, the server wont even render that control for the client. +1

Answer (score 0):

Get it using the ID:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var hv= $('#test2').val();
        });
    </script>
```

More Info here: [Get Value for Hidden Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091374/get-value-from-hidden-field-jquery)

Comment: According to the debugger, hv is coming up as undefined.

Comment: I updated the post and to clarify, I have verified that test2 is getting set with the correct value in the code behind.

Comment: make sure the jquery runs after the page is done loading

    $(document).ready(function () {
    }

Answer (score 0):

In your hiddenfield element you are using attribute Visible="false", It means hidden field will not render in to the webform, remove that attribute and try.
anyways hiddenfield will not be visible in webform.