# Play Framework 2.5 CSRF check failed ajax

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I don't want to enable CSRF filter for all my requests.
But want to use it in my form.
So I use CSRFAddToken and CSRFCheck like this in controller:

```
  def change(lng: String) = checkToken {
      Action { implicit request =>
          registerForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            { formWithErrors =>
              Ok(Json.toJson(JsObject(Map("status" -> JsString("error"), "message" -> JsString(messagesApi.translate("register.all_fields_required", Seq()).get)))))
            },
            value =>
              [Code was cutted]
          )
      }
    }

  def getCurrent(lng: String) = addToken {
    Action { implicit request =>
        Ok(views.html.profile_edit_popup())
    }
  }
```

In view I just use

```
@CSRF.formField
```

to add CSRF to form
Then I get getCurrent action using Ajax and getting html for form and on save I post it using Ajax to change action. The problem is I'm getting

> CSRF token check failed

error on submit. Even so I see CSRF hidden field in the form. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your jQuery or whatever isn't picking up `csrfToken` field correctly?

Comment: You also need to set the `Csrf-Token` header! See [this example](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/9008dd9a93ff7fcfcfba8c182903b0a997beb034/ui/app/scripts/app.js#L62). Note that there CSRF token is sent as custom Cookie(see app.conf).

Comment: @insan-e you were right. Can you make it answer?

Comment: Yup, thanks! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your JavaScript library isn't picking up `csrfToken` field correctly? For example you could have [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091374/get-value-from-hidden-field-jquery) when using jQuery's `text()` instead of `val()`...

Depending on your config settings, you could be missing `Csrf-Token` value. Play wants the CSRF token in headers(session) AND (in form OR query string). More info [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf#Plays-CSRF-protection).